# PrettyPhoto - passing unique parameter from iframe window to parent page

Tags: jquery, iframe, callback, jquery-callback, prettyphoto

I've recently started using prettyphoto to display a video.

This is my current setup

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var lastClicked = null;
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    callback: function()
    {           
        if(lastClicked != null) {
                var topicid = lastClicked.data("topicid"); 
                $.post('/course/close-video', {topic_id: topicid });
                lastClicked = null;
        }
    }
    }).click(function (){
        lastClicked = $(this);
});
</script>


<a data-topicid="<?php echo $topic->topic_id;?>" href="/course/play-video/topic_id/<?php echo $topic->topic_id;?>?iframe=true&width=470&height=340" rel="prettyPhoto" title="<?php echo $topic->topic_name;?>">
<img src="/images/videos/<?php echo $image_name;?>" width="170" height="103" alt="<?php echo $topic->topic_name;?>"/>
</a>
```

This is what is happening

1) When a user clicks on the link - the play-video php action is called which retrives the video url from database and passes so that it can be played on the popup window. This works fine.

2) Now the play-video also generates a unique id which is passed on to the page (iframe window) where the video is played. Right now I'm just displaying that value on the page. I can have that unique id stored as a hidden field or as a div value.

3) Now when the user closes this window - how can I access this unique id in the callback function of pretty photo which is in the main page.

Thanks a lot 
Appreciate your time

Comment: hi Gublooo, what video player are you using?

Comment: Its viddler - my videos are stored there - I get the embed code from the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable on the main page.

```
var UniqueId; //Unique ID that will arrive from the iframe
```

Now a function to write the value

```
function setUniqeId(val) {
    UniqueId = val;
}
```

Now inside the iframe, where the id, has already been receive, pass it to the parent like

```
parent.setUniqueId(TheIdThatIHaveReceived);
```

### Update:

Make sure the script to read is after the DOM is loaded. One of the early ways of ensuring this, is placing the script after the Elements

```
<input id="topic_user_id" type="text" />
<script>
var unique_id = document.getElementById("topic_user_id").value;
parent.setUniqueId(unique_id);
</script>
```

One of the modern techniques would be to create a event handler like

```
window.onload = function() {
    var unique_id = document.getElementById("topic_user_id").value;
    parent.setUniqueId(unique_id);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Starx - I tried your approach but I'm getting stuck in reading the unique id in the javscript code of the iframe - i tried setting the unique id both as a div and hidden field - but in the javascript I'm not able to read that value so I can pass that value to parent.setUniqueId function. - Egs <input type="hidden" id="topic_user_id" name="topic_user_id" value="1980"/> Or
<div id="topic_user_id">1980</div>

Comment: In the javascript - I tried reading using var unique_id =  document.getElementById("topic_user_id").value; for the hidden field and var id =  document.getElementById("topic_user_id").innerHTML; and when I do the alert - it doesn't even reach there. Thanks

Comment: @Gublooo, the script cannot read the element unless they are loaded onto the DOM, place the script of `parent.setUniqueId()` after the `div` or `input`

Comment: Thanks Starx - that worked perfectly. Appreciate your time and inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    callback: function() {           
        active_link = $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto'].active");
        topic_id = $(active_link).data('topicid');
        $(active_link).removeClass('active');
        alert(topic_id);
        $.post('/course/close-video', {topic_id: topic_id});
    }
}).click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

This adds a class named "active" to the clicked link so that you can easily target it in the callback. It also removes the class inside of the callback to prevent re-selecting the most recent link clicked.

Comment: Hello Chaney - your code seems to be getting the topic_id - I'm already getting the topic_id in my current code. My question is when I click on the link that opens up the prettyphoto dialog to play the video - the link calls the play-video php script which generates a unique_id and retrieves the video URL which is displayed in the popup. Now when the user closes the popup - how do I get the unique_id that was generated...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just get the value from the hiddenfield when the callback function is trigged.

`myvideo` is the ID of the iframe. If only one iframe will exist in the DOM, just use `iframe` as selector (without the hash). `hidden` is the ID of the hiddenfield inside the iframe.

```
var value = $("#myvideo").contents().find('#hidden').val();
alert(value);
```

I created a JS fiddle for you so you can see how to get the value from an iframe.
http://jsfiddle.net/vtDRW/

Its pretty straight forward I think. So just open the iframe where you have placed a hiddenvalue and get it when the callback is fired.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var lastClicked = null;
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    callback: function()
    {           
        if(lastClicked != null) {
                var topicid = lastClicked.data("topicid"); 
                var iframeValue = $("#IFRAME_ID").contents().find('#HIDDEN_ID').val();
                $.post('/course/close-video', {topic_id: topicid });
                lastClicked = null;
        }
    }
    }).click(function (){
        lastClicked = $(this);
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Simon - but in my above setup - the prettyphoto iframe is invoked by clicking the link - where do I specify the id for the the iframe